# lebesgue and riemann integrals are the same for continuous functions on $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral

I have a proof in front of me which goes as follows, firstly assuming that the function $f \geq 0$ on $[a,b]$. We get a partition $a = x_0 < x_1 <....<x_n = b$ with $x_i - x_{i-1} = (b-a)/2^n$ and define $$ f_n(x) = \inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)$$ for $i = 1,...,n$ and $f_n(a) = m_1$. Then the author states $f_n$ is increasing to $f$. could someone explain why this is?

Comment: here is a link to the proof https://i.gyazo.com/1f4fd71cdd23dc82b7f7720a936091e9.png

Comment: The definition of $f_n(x)$ seems incorrect, as the right-hand side is not a function of $n$, nor is it a function of $x$ after taking the infimum. (It is a function of $i$.)

Comment: @Bungo yes, that's why I don't understand it

Comment: $f_n$ is a step function which is the lower-approximation to $f$. It depends on $n$ through the number of subintervals in the partition.

Comment: Should be $f_n(x) = \sum \inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x) 1_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the intent of the proof to define

$$f_n(x) = \sum_{i} \inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x) 1_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}.$$

Consider a subinterval $I_{n,k} = [a + k(b-a)/2^n, a+ (k+1)(b-a)/2^n].$

Since $I_{n+1,k} \subset I_{n,k}$ and $I_{n+1,k+1} \subset I_{n,k}$  we have

$$\inf_{x \in I_{n+1,k}}f(x)\geqslant \inf_{x \in I_{n,k}}f(x), \\ \inf_{x \in I_{n+1,k+1}}f(x)\geqslant \inf_{x \in I_{n,k}}f(x).$$

This can be used to show that $f_n$ is increasing.

Convergence $f_n \to f$ follows because for any $x$ we have $x \in I_{n,k}$ for some $k$ and $x$ is within $(b-a)/2^n$ of the point at which $f$ is minimum on the interval.  Since $f$ is continuous the difference between $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ can be made arbitrarly small for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: I understand that's increasing, but from how the author has defined $f_n(x)$, I don't see how it's increasing as the definition of $f_n$ depends on $i$

Comment: $f_n$ should be the step function defined on $[a,b]$ as I point out above for this to work.

Comment: but if it's defined as a sum as you did, then the subinterval argument you gave doesn't really make sense, as $f$ is positive, the sum for $n$ and $n+1$ will have one extra term, which will definitely be positive so it's increasing?

Comment: No -- that is the point of the dyadic partition. Increasing $n$ by $1$ splits each interval into $2$ subintervals. In other words why is $2^n$ used here instead of just $n$.

Comment: You're welcome.  This is a pretty standard argument that you might find in Royden. But you are correct -- if the length of the interval is $(b-a)/n$ this won't work.