# Dirac delta definition with $i \epsilon$.

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, dirac-delta

I am asked to prove that: $$\delta(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \Im \bigg(\frac{1}{x-i\epsilon}\bigg)$$ defines a Dirac delta function.

For one, $\Im\big(\frac{1}{x-i \epsilon}\big) = \frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}$ and integrating over $x$ gives $\arctan(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$ so, for all $\epsilon >0$ we come up with $1$.

I'm left with showing $$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\int\frac{\epsilon}{x^2 + \epsilon^2} f(x) dx = f(0)$$

I tried a Taylor expansion of $\frac{\epsilon}{x^2 + \epsilon^2}$ around $\epsilon \approx 0$ but that didn't simply the problem for me much. Can someone show me the proof?

Comment: just for accuracy's sake, I believe maybe the $\epsilon$ in the denominator in the second formula should be squared

Comment: Good point, I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of variables $x=\epsilon t$ shows that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac\epsilon{x^2+\epsilon^2}f(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac1{t^2+1}f(\epsilon t)dt$$
Now $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0}f(\epsilon t)=f(0)$ and by the dominated convergence theorem
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac1{t^2+1}f(\epsilon t)dt=
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac1{t^2+1}f(0)dt=\pi f(0)$$

Comment: is it clear this is a lebesgue integral?

Comment: @qbert, I do not understand what you mean. $f$ is a test function.

Comment: you used dominated convergence, why is this ok? OP did not say this was a lebesgue integral.

Comment: @qbert: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1742806). The result cited there is correct, at least.

Comment: @robjohn right, I know that the lebesgue and riemann integrals agree when both exist for a function, but does it follow that the Riemann integral inherits the nice convergence properties in the above?

Comment: @qbert: Each $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is the same and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is the same, where would a problem lay?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For any $t\gt0$, what is
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1\pi\int_{-t}^t\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Next, find a $t\gt0$ so that for $|x|\le t$, $|f(x)-f(0)|$ is small.